# spark ML pipeline gives different values for different runs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

i have a pipeline with same input (cached dataframe),
i am changing just one stage every time (the algorithm itself , logistic regression , random forest , etc)
doing fit on the trained data +  transform on the test data , and checking log likelihhod on the prediction .
i am getting it by using also the trials column , as i understand - this column should not change by the pipeline , it is a supplied value , just the prediction should change.
what am i missing ?

```
finish training data, start transform data
total liklihood for algorithm : logistic_regression
+------------------+---------+--------------------+
|            lk_sum|lk_trials|     final_liklihood|
+------------------+---------+--------------------+
|-1181.226211424361|  21855.0|-0.05404832813655278|
+------------------+---------+--------------------+

finish training data, start transform data
total liklihood for algorithm : GBTRegressor
]+------------------+---------+--------------------+
|            lk_sum|lk_trials|     final_liklihood|
+------------------+---------+--------------------+
|-794.1915302136496|  21376.0|-0.03715342113649184|
+------------------+---------+--------------------+

finish training data, start transform data
 total liklihood for algorithm : random_forest
+-------------------+---------+--------------------+
|             lk_sum|lk_trials|     final_liklihood|
+-------------------+---------+--------------------+
|-1494.7763490404889|  22509.0|-0.06640794122530938|
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code you used ?

Comment: it is just a select from parquet files , it uses random split , but the point is that the rest of the pipeline stays the same , just the algorithm changes .
the data is cached before all the pipelines , so it should be constant ....